# elegant way of graceful stopping queue with periodic consumers by timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, message-queue

I have a queue with multiple producers - one consumer. The consumer runs periodically and drains the queue fully (no messages left after).
A graceful algorithm should run the consumer and wait for it with timeout or just wait if the consumer is already running.

Currently we have smth like this:

```
void stop(boolean graceful) {
        if (graceful && !checkAndStopDirectly()) {
            executor.shutdown();
            try {
                if (!executor.awaitTermination(shutdownWaitInterval, shutdownWaitIntervalUnit)) {
                    log.warn("...");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("...", e);
            }
        } else {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }

private boolean checkAndStopDirectly() {
    ExecutorService shutdownExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
        return shutdownExecutor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                if (isAlreadyRan.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    try {
                        runnableDrainTask.run();
                    } finally {
                        isAlreadyRan.set(false);
                    }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }).get(shutdownWaitInterval, shutdownWaitIntervalUnit);
```

Does anybody see more elegant way to do it?
e.g. I'm looking a way w/o using additional AtomicBoolean (isAlreadyRan) or double waiting logic with time intervals as object fields etc.
btw, the poison pill pattern comes to my mind...

Comment: Can you be clearer with your requirements? what should wait? A client to the stop() call? what should it wait for, the queue to drain? Do you want a call to stop() to block until the thing is drained, no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking here about a graceful shutdown of your application should do the following?

1. wait for the queue to drain, or
2. timeout if the drain is taking too long

I might need to understand how you drain the queue but if you're able to do that in such a way as that it is interruptible, you can timeout on the get of the `Future` and attempt a `shutdownNow` (interrupting if not fully drained) regardless; how does this look to you?

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void stop() {
    try {
        pool.submit(new DrainTask()).get(100, MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // nada, the timeout indicates the queue hasn't drained yet
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nada, defer to finally
    } finally {
        pool.shutdownNow();
    }
}

private class DrainTask implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            ; // drain away
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is the `compareAndSet` part used to guard against multiple concurrent calls to `stop`? I think I'd favor a general lock or use `synchronized` instead. However, in the event of a conflict, an `ExecutionException` would be thrown and repeating calls to `shutdownNow` are fine.

It kind of relies on the `DrainTask` being able to stop what's its doing in response to a call to interrupt (as `shutdownNow` will attempt to call interrupt on any currently running threads).